# Facebook and iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there an open source API that allow me to post on groups of Facebook? Secondly, do I need to create an application for that or no need? I'd like to do that through iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [the Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) and simple HTTP requests (using the iOS SDK) to do this. There's also an actively developed [open source Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) that should make this process even easier.

Comment: I installed git in order to use their open source API . but do I need to create Facebook app to enable me posting on Facebook group?  for git to test their demo i need to create Facebook app. any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to register your mobile app to use the Facebook API. [Read up on authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [register your app here](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/).

Comment: I have also posted a code snippet here, explaining how to upload an image via graph api. You may find it useful for figuring out how things work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632842/cant-post-to-facebook-with-graph-api-iphone/7649619#7649619

Answer (score -1):

FaceBook has an [API](http://developers.facebook.com/) - have you checked to see if what you want to do is supported?

As far as their being a need - FaceBook has their own iOS app.  Do you want to do something that it can't already do?