# Cant Post To Facebook with Graph API iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

i have implemented this sample code below to get a connection to the user feed post

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"197765190297119" andDelegate:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];


}
```

and this sample code is called when the user logs in... it calls now by a button pressed for check, but dosent do any, perhaps i can get a dialog feed insted

```
    NSString *str=@"Your String to post";

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               str,@"message",
                               @"Test it!",@"name",                                   
                               nil];
Facebook *fb = [[Facebook alloc] init];
[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
               andParams:params
           andHttpMethod:@"POST"
             andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Are you letting the user log in in anyway? If so, could you show some code? You should probably be using the same "Facebook" object for doing the graph request as you used for logging the user in.

Comment: - (void)fbDidLogin {
    // store the access token and expiration date to the user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:facebook.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

Comment: i think i just got a big mess with this process can you try to help me to get along this process correctly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a walkthrough of uploading an image to the facebook wall. I copied this out of an older application, the current facebook API works a little bit different. I think you can see my main point of using a shared facebook object, which you use to do the authentication and also the requests to the API. I took out a few things to make it easier to understand. Apple actually wants you to check for an existing internet connection. I hope it helps.

```
@synthesize facebook;

//login with facebook
- (IBAction) facebookButtonPressed {
    if (!facebook || ![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        self.facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSArray *perms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"read_stream", @"create_note", nil];
        [facebook authorize:FACEBOOK_API_KEY permissions:perms delegate:self];
    }
    else {
        [self fbDidLogin];
    }
}

//upload image once you're logged in
-(void) fbDidLogin {
    [self fbUploadImage];
}

- (void) fbUploadImage
{
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    resultImage, @"picture",
                                    nil];
    [facebook requestWithMethodName: @"photos.upload" 
                          andParams: params
                      andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                        andDelegate: self]; 

    self.currentAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook", @"")  
                             message:NSLocalizedString(@"Uploading to Facebook.", @"")  
                             delegate:self 
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];

    [self.currentAlertView show];
}

//facebook error
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{

    [self.currentAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.currentAlertView = nil;

    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")  
                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook error message", @"")
                            delegate:self 
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}

//facebook success
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    [self.currentAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.currentAlertView = nil;

    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook", @"") 
                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Uploaded to Facebook message", @"")
                            delegate:self 
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}
```